# scala play Read json conditionally populate case class

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I have a json that I'm reading using play json api with Read.

```
 {
  "runId" : "123",
  "name" : "ABC",
  "location" : "DEF"
}

implicit val jsonRead: Reads[Contact] = (
        (JsPath \ "runId").readWithDefault(generateRunId) and
          (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
          (JsPath \ "location").read[String]
    )(Contact.apply _)

case class Contact(runId : String, name : String, location : String, rerun : Boolean)
```

I want to add the last attribute **rerun** in the *Contact* so that when "runId" does exists in the json file, it would be set to true. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readNullable` and `map`:

```
implicit val jsonRead: Reads[Contact] = (
  (JsPath \ "runId").readWithDefault(generateRunId) and
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "location").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "runId").readNullable[String].map(_.nonEmpty)
)(Contact.apply _)
```